# How to extract the numbers with signage within the square bracket from the text file and store them in array (java)? Also, I want to exclude that 97

Tags: java

How to extract the numbers with signage within the square bracket from the text file and store them in the array (java)?  Also, I want to exclude that 97 while storing.

```
[-4646759,-4201117,-3970467,-3952785,-3751128,-3334084,-3241453,-2992243,-
2514542,-2213147,-2120566,-1822732,-1468790,-1316752,-1083219,-601869,-
541900,-531605,-430222,-285809]97
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option, using a string split on the input followed by a stream to create a list of long integers:

```java
String input = "[-4646759,-4201117,-3970467,-3952785,-3751128,-3334084,-3241453,-2992243,-2514542,-2213147,-2120566,-1822732,-1468790,-1316752,-1083219,-601869,-541900,-531605,-430222,-285809]97";
List<Long> nums = Arrays.stream(input.replaceAll("^.*\\[|\\].*$", "").split(","))
    .map(Long::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(nums);
```

This prints:

```
[-4646759, -4201117, -3970467, -3952785, -3751128, -3334084, -3241453,
 -2992243, -2514542, -2213147, -2120566, -1822732, -1468790, -1316752,
 -1083219, -601869, -541900, -531605, -430222, -285809]
```

Comment: I am trying to get the input by text file through command line. Could you please help me how to store them in arraylist after replacing and splitting.

Comment: Do you want to store them as strings or as numbers?

Comment: numbers please. I am using Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); after that trying to store them in number array, but it is not working. May be I am missing something? Please help

Comment: Check the updated answer for one possibility.  My answer starts assuming you already have your input as a Java string.  If not, then find someone to get to that starting point.